# What equipment should I have to kill the Eye of Cthulhu?

Tags: terraria

I just manually summoned the Eye of Cthulhu, going into battle with copper armour, tungsten broadsword, gold bow, jester arrows and plenty of lesser healing potions. I came rather close to death but I managed to stay alive. However, the Eye took off when I had his health down to ~1700. I'm assuming this means you only have a few minutes to finish it off after a certain point. Is there any equipment I'm missing to help kill the Eye faster and to help my survivability?
If it's relevant, my current life is 120.

Comment: The Eye of Cthulhu can only be fought at night time, which is why it went away after a while (night ended). One thing you can do is only summon it when the night has just begun. Better armour would help with survivability as well, but there's really no "requirements", as long as you can do enough damage to kill it before sunrise.

Comment: Strategic use of platforms will help too. That way, you'll be able to dodge left/right, AND up/down. Usually I manage to kill it without armour, 100hp, and silver bow+broadsword.

Comment: I recommend a "Blue Moon"/ "Ball 'O' Hurt" / any other flail as these are very effective vs. spawns. Musket is VERY nice, too (if you can afford the ammunition)

Comment: I recommend regeneration potion and shurikens (~500), at least for the first time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no "requirements" as when you are ready. You can just be well prepared.

Things to know about the Eye of Cthulhu:

- Can only be fought at night, that means spawn him as soon as it's ~7:30 ingame.
- Nighttime lasts about 9 minutes.
- Cthulhu First Form does 15 damage and has 1400 life.
- Cthulhu Second Form does 23 damage and has 1400 life.

More info: http://terraria.gamepedia.com.

Comment: I would add that he runs off when night time is over, which it sounds like is what happened in OP's case.

Comment: EoC has double the health these days.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a world with Crimson, some of the Crimson Hearts drop Crimson Rods. This is a very easy way to farm the Eye, just place the reaincloud above your head and keep dodging  in the vicinity of the raincloud.

Don't try to go for it with meelee weapons. Shurikens work great here, or a minishark if you have the cash. And keep dodging if you have low level gear.

The Eye will only stay around at nighttime.

I currently farm the Eye by just staying put with a crimson cloud above me, and whacking it with a Vilethorn. You can get around 7 a night with that.

Answer (score 1):

I find that the armor does not matter much, as long as you have at least iron armor.

The best weapon to fight it in my opinion is flaming arrows. When I fought it, it was using a gold bow with flaming arrows. The gold bow set up for high initial damage, and the flames damaged it over time, making its health go down more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I have defeated Cthulhu a good 5 times with a gold or demonite bow so u should go with the bow. When using flaming arrows the Cthulhu lights on fire for a few seconds, taking extra damage. I suggest either copper or iron armor for your first battle. PS I have terraria videos on everyplay

Answer (score -1):

[Eye of Cthulhu](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Eye_of_Cthulhu#Strategy) is a breeze if you try and get gear from the [Dungeon](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Gold_Chest#Dungeon), after killing Skeletron, or the [Underworld](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Shadow_Chest), after getting the shadow key from the Dungeon. Alternatively, and if you have enough explosives since you can't mine the blocks, you could blow up enough corruption/crimson in your world (depending on which it has) to destroy [Shadow Orbs](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Shadow_Orb) or [Crimson Hearts](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Crimson_Heart). Both of these drop fairly good gear if you are willing to spawn a boss every 3rd destroy. If you can't do any of these at the moment and are just setting your sights on the Eye of Cthulhu, I might recommend just exploring the underground and the [caverns](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Cavern) for [golden chests](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Golden_Chest#Underground) and also simply mining.  Gear you get from the chests will occupy your accessory slots and for your weapons you can pray you get something good from the rare drops enemies have, like a [bone sword](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Bone_Sword), or make weapons yourself. The best self-crafted gear you can get from mining before hardmode 'll be [gold armor](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Gold_armor) or [platinum armor](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Platinum_armor), depending on what spawns in your map.

As people are saying, you *don't* have any specific requirements for beating the Eye of Cthulhu or any of the [pre-Hardmode Bosses](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Boss#Pre-Hardmode_Bosses) for that matter, but gear makes it much easier on you.

Answer (score -1):

Molten armour and is best. Break a shadow orb or crimson heart A meteorite will land and give you access to phasesaber's

Comment: Molten armor is in a way higher league than the eye of Cthulhu, Molten armor is more Pre-Hardmode end game equipment. Also, a shadow orb/Crimson heart (if enough are broken) will spawn either a  Eater of Worlds or the Brain of Cthulhu.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend having silver armor, sword, and bow but it is not needed. I would recommend bringing potions and if possible a friend who has already beat him. All of these is not really a necessity but It will make the fight a lot easier. Make sure to wait outside in the corruption just before dark and start spamming the button to spawn the eye of Cthulhu so you can have all night but it probably wouldn't take all night to fight him. Full tungsten would probably make a 100% chance as long as you do enough damage.

Answer (score -1):

i recommend using molten armor and having full life pts and use a blade of grass and for your ranged weapon you should use a space gun it works so well the eye of cthulhu should only take 1 heart from you

Answer (score -3):

**Eye Of Cthulhu**

- Silver Armor
- Silver Bourdsword
- Silver Bow

Answer (score -3):

I usually have demonite armor and demonite axe. Now whenever I spawn him, I MOST LIKELY will kill him. I don't want to risk me dying, so I always use demonite against him. That makes even his second form easy peasy.

Comment: Why do you use this equipment?  Telling us what you use is a start, but a really good answer tells us *why*, as well.

Answer (score -3):

Use silver armor set, gold bow with 80 jester arrow, and a melee just in case...and some lesser healing potion. I killed 2 cthulhu in one night with this set.

Answer (score -3):

I have beaten the eye of cthulu with a ancient cobalt helmet iron chestpiece and ancient cobalt boots.  I had a platinum broadsword, a flare gun (not really needed), and a emerald staff.  It is an easy kill if you have all this stuff.

Comment: See [this comment](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/174548/what-equipment-should-i-have-to-kill-the-eye-of-cthulhu/201543#comment251448_185419)