# What equipment should I have to kill the Eye of Cthulhu on expert mode?

Tags: terraria

I want to defeat the Eye of Cthulhu, but I think I'm unprepared. What do I need to defeat him?

[Similar to this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/174548/what-equipment-should-i-have-to-kill-the-eye-of-cthulhu), except I am asking about the more difficult expert mode, as opposed to the regular mode.

Comment: Close Voters, this question is in no way too broad for arqade. We get questions of similar context all the time. [Here is an almost identical question asking about the same boss on an easier setting](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/174548/what-equipment-should-i-have-to-kill-the-eye-of-cthulhu).

Comment: Due to the context of "I think I'm unprepared" and "What do I need", I am also changing the question to specifically ask about equipment.

Comment: @Timelord64 It looks like you've modified the question to ask the same thing as the duplicate now.  Expert mode notwithstanding, which I don't think warrants a separate question.

Comment: @Frank, expert mode is a differant mode to regular, and warrants more powerful equipment. The boss is not only stronger, but **it also behaves differantly**. Regardless, this already went through the close vote post-edit, and it failed.

Answer (score 1):

What I personally used in the fight was

- Meteor Armor and Space gun because while wearing the Meteor Armor the Space Gun is completely free to use and it provides the same protection as Gold. Just go to the Corruption or Crimson, smash the respective orb or heart, and you have a 50% chance of one landing at midnight. One crash should be enough for the set.
- Swiftness potion to help dodge the attacks, Ironskin is always helpful, and Regen for obvious reasons, Some kind of food for the Well Fed buff to stop the half regen that comes with expert and extra stats are always nice,
- A Grappling Hook, Hermes Boots, and double jump item for even more mobility, then get other defensive items for whatever you like, a defensive enchanted shackle even could help. Maybe even keep a Nurse nearby so if you have gotten hit too many times you can heal.
- A Campfire and (if you can) a Heart Lamp, and Honey for more regen, and a Sunflower because it reduces spawn rates of annoying enemies that you would have to deal with otherwise and another speed boost.
- My arena consists of only a few long rows of platforms for extra mobility to dodge those evil dash attacks he uses near the end.

Good luck with the eye! The shield is amazing, totally worth the prep for it.

Answer (score -1):

I've soloed the eye in regular, no armor, only the bees knees. My suggestion, Hermes boots(warding) your best armor(platinum if not molten, meteor, or shadow/crimson) bees knees, about a stack of healers (regular if not minor) a stack and a half of arrows, and any other equips with warding modifiers.

Most efficient way I know of.